# SQL query returning questions marks

Tags: sql, encoding

I am trying to run a SQL query on a MariaDB database but it's returning question marks. The text I am expecting to be returned is in Japanese.

I tried using the following but there is no change in the results.

```
SELECT convert(column_name using utf8) from table where id="1"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is more likely to be the *display* of the text which is appearing as question marks. How are you displaying it?

Comment: I am running a python script containing the query on a server. Initially, japanese text written in the script were also appearing as question marks (while viewing through bash shell using the editor nano) . I solved this by adding `export LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"` in my bash_profile. But there is no change in the query results. I am just using the print statement in python to print the results from the query. I am having no problem running the script on my local machine though (while connecting to the same database on the server).

Comment: You can use [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) in Python to check the character values to investigate where it is going wrong.

Comment: ord seems to return 63, which is the code for '?'.

Comment: OK, so now you test the characters in the DB and see what they are. I'm sure you get the idea of how to continue from there.